# Inverse square law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity

> The radius of Planet C is close to half that of Earth, and both have the same average density. Compared to Earth’s gravitational acceleration at the surface, approximately what will Planet C’s gravity be at its surface?

Is it 1/4 g because of the inverse square law?

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming the mass is the same, and focusing on the inverse square dependence on radius.  But it's not given that the mass is the same, it is given that the density is the same.  So calculate the mass ratio, and include that mass difference along with the radius difference.